# Java - Hide All JButtons

Tags: java

I there any way to hide all of the `JButtons` within a class without having to individually set `myButton.setVisible(false);` ?

I'm looking for something where I can with 1 line of code hide them all without having to constantly update a list of `JButton`s.

If anyone knows of a way to make this possible would be much appreciated.

Comment: put your buttons into an array, create a method that just runs a for loop and turns them all visible or invisible.

Comment: Where these buttons are added?

Comment: Depending on how your buttons are laid out... If they are all on a single JPanel, you can just setVisible(false) on that panel. *With no other components on that panel.

Comment: They're added on a sidePanel which expands and partially hides when you click a button, i want the buttons to hide when the panel partially closes and show when it expands - but there will be a lot of buttons being added to the panel over time, so its a pain to add all the setVisible statements - i'm going to try @mig array idea, ty!

Comment: Best bet would be to put them in some kind of container,  an `array` and iterate through them. That or add those specific buttons to a `swing container` and set that visibility to `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from Root Component and iterate all the the underlying components using `recursive` function to hide all `JButton`.

Sample code to hide all `JButton` added in `JFrame` or `JPanel` or both.

Note: Extend recursion function for other components also.

Just single call to `hide()` method will take care of this stub.

```
public  void hide(Component parent) {
    if (parent instanceof JFrame) {
        JFrame frame = (JFrame) parent;
        for (int i = 0; i < frame.getContentPane().getComponentCount(); i++) {
            Component comp = frame.getContentPane().getComponent(i);

            if (comp instanceof JButton) {
                comp.setVisible(false);
            } else {
                hide(comp);
            }
        }
    } else if (parent instanceof JPanel) {
        JPanel panel = (JPanel) parent;
        for (int i = 0; i < panel.getComponentCount(); i++) {
            Component comp = panel.getComponent(i);
            if (comp instanceof JButton) {
                comp.setVisible(false);
            } else {
                hide(comp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```